# How secure is offline data stored on clients by Firebases Realtime Database?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

The [documentation on Offline Capabilites](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/offline-capabilities) of the Firebase Realtime Database explains how Firebase provides tools for persisting data locally on the client:

> By enabling persistence, any data that the Firebase Realtime Database client would sync while online persists to disk and is available offline, even when the user or operating system restarts the app. This means your app works as it would online by using the local data stored in the cache.

However, there is no information about how the persisted data is stored or how it is secured.

**Question:** Is the database encrypted before it is persisted to the devices internal storage? Is the local database protected from being read by an attacker who extracts it from the devices storage via `adb` or other methods?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*firebaser here*

The on-device cache is not encrypted. It is readable by anyone who has access to the device storage.

Comment: Why is the on-device cache not encrypted? Is this a planned feature?

Comment: Mr Puffelen, is it still the same? If yes, then how can I make it secure myself?